# Yii2 Custom / Shorter Namespace

Tags: module, namespaces, yii2

I have a nested 'mail' module in my yii2 (basic template) at this location:

> @app/modules/admin/modules/mail

How do I create shorter namespaces in all of the modules files. So instead of this namespace in my controller files:

> namespace app\modules\admin\modules\mail\controllers;

I could just have:

> namespace mail/controllers;

If I ever move the module folder, I wouldn't have to go and manually change the namespace in every single file (also they're just long).

The docs actually recommend this here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html#nested-modules where it says "**you should consider using a shorter namespace here!**"

But how do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

you must set alias to directory at bootstrap to custom namespace.

First, create a `bootstrap.php` in `config/` folder:

```
//bootstrap.php
Yii::setAlias('mail', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/modules/admin/modules/mail');
```

Add run `bootstrap.php` at init app.

Edit file `web/index.php`, add this line after require `Yii.php`

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

//Add after require Yii.php
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Now you can set namespace for controllers in mail module is `mail/controllers`.

Hope it helpful.