# How to add own namespace in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, php-namespaces

I have changed Yii2 advanced directory structure like following(it's working well):

```
app-folder
 -admin
   -assets
   -.htaccess
   -index.php
 -assets
 -protected
   -backend
     ...
   -common
     ...
   -frontend
     ...
   ...
 -uploads
 ...
```

Now, I am trying to add a namespace as `namespace protected\base;` into `protected/base/AnyFile.php` file and use it in a controller as `use protected\base\AnyFile;`. But, my project is giving error:

`syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) or \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)`

I saw this issue on the website: [Yii2 Custom / Shorter Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033580/yii2-custom-shorter-namespace). However, It didn't work on my condition.

Comment: Why not use: protected\components\AnyFile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `protected` is reserved keyword (token T_PROTECTED). You can keep direcory name but you need to change namespace root alias.

In your alias config file `protected/common/bootstrap.php` write:

```
Yii::setAlias('app', dirname(dirname(__DIR__))); // set path to protected directory
```

And then use `namespace app\base;` and `use app\base\AnyFile;`.

See Class Autoloading section of the guide https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-autoloading